# What does ”めえ” in ”めえ～て注意してよ” mean?

Tags: meaning

[Source](https://youtu.be/Z0ZZOfQZ_0Y?t=153)

I may have heard it wrong, so the phrase I'm asking for can be heard from the link above.

I was watching a Youtube clip and I heard "めえ～て注意してよ", and I suppose that "め" is something you say to show disapproval? But I couldn't find anything on the dictionary so does anyone know what "め" means in this context and how to use it?

Comment: Related: Read そーれお茶's answer in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-do-you-say-no-to-stop-someone/60214#60214

Comment: The dictionary "spelling" is 「めっ」.　 https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%81%E3%81%A3/#jn-244620